# MS project - outline number in to do list report

Tags: ms-project

I have lot of tasks with similar names and hard to identify them in the to do list report.

Is there a way to show the outline number next to the task name. (In report, I could see it in Gantt view by Format -> Show/Hide -> Outline Number)?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the WBS column on your Gantt view, this column has the same value used for the outline number. The report should then include that new column and now you can identify the tasks.